# Jquery Scroll detect

Tags: jquery, css

i want a simple JS code to detect Scrolling of HTML page.

Check this page : 
http://conf.iranwebfestival.com/

As you scroll the page, the top menu elements, get CSS borders .

I need somthing to do that .

Comment: have you tried anything? show some code etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a function `scrollTop` to find how much screen was scrolled down. Here is base of using

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var ScrolledDown = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

and here is a example how to use jQuery's function scrollTop - and avoid scrolling if you achieved bottom of page.

[Switch div from fixed to absolute at bottom of browser (see my answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350480/switch-div-from-fixed-to-absolute-at-bottom-of-browser/21524092#21524092)

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky, for next advice - but at this time I only would like to know explanation of reverse of 200 points of reputation I got by upvotes yesterday. What happened?

Comment: A quick [glance at your profile screen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3263387/vaclav?tab=reputation) shows that you were flagged for "serial up-voting".  You'll have to go over to meta stackoverflow and ask the moderators about this.

Answer (score 1):

That page doen't render properly on my device..
But to detect scrolling with jQuery, I'd check the value of `$(window).scrollTop()`, and if it was bigger than 0, it would mean the user had scrolled. Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() // when user scrolls
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0)
        // scrollbar is not at the top
    else
        // scrollbar is at the top
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's very much your responsibility to prove you have at least tried, googled it, whatever, and you have not done this, this answer is simple enough in jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //Whatever you want to do
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).
Or if you're using Bootstrap look into Scrollspy.

You should put some effort into implementing it. A simple search would have got you what you wanted.